# How to check for " " using explode

Tags: php

How do use explode to check for " ".

Thanks
Jean

Comment: why do you want to use explode? do you have an example situation you can show?

Comment: strpos($string,' ') !== false would be the normal method to check for a space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short : **you dont.**

Long :

```
if(count(explode(' ',$data))>1) echo "GOT A SPACE";
```

Correct :

```
if(strpos($data,' ')!==false) echo "GOT A SPACE";
```

Comment: Dammit - posted before me :-P I was going to post the same about not doing it this way too - thanks for saving me the effort I guess ;-)

Comment: +1. One performance thing: `explode(' ',$data,2)` would be sufficient because we're just looking for at least one occurence of a space. However, `strpos` would obviously be the best choice here.

Answer (score 4):

what do you mean? As in, check if there is a space in a string by using explode?

```
if (count(explode(" ",$string)) > 1) {
  // has 1 or more space
}
```

But this isn't the most efficient way to do it.  You should instead use strpos()

Comment: duplicate answer, with error (not complaining, just reminding :) )

Comment: "posted at the same time as someone else" answer. thanks for pointing out error though :)

Comment: explode returns array("String"); if delim. is not found in String

Comment: yes you are right, I somehow managed to forget that as well. I thought you were talking about the _ in str_pos